# exact sequence in group, $0 \to \ker f \to A \to B \to 0$ and subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

Let $f:A \to B$ be a group surjective homomorphism,
There is a exact sequence in group,
$0 \to \ker f \to A \to B \to 0$.

Suppose $\ker f$ has no torsion element, and $A$ has subgroup isomorphic to
Klein four group $\mathbb{Z/2Z\times Z/2Z}$.

Then, why $B$ has subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z/2Z\times Z/2Z}$ ?

My though: If this exact sequence spilts, then every torsion part of $A$ is to $B$, so I can say the result. But in general, I think this exact sequence does not spilt, so I'm stuck.

$A/ \ker f$ is isomorphic to $B$, from here, can I say something・・　？

Comment: As currently stated, you're asking in your third sentence why $B$ has a subgroup isomorphic to the Klein four group, but in your second sentence, you assume this is already the case. I guess there is a typo somewhere?

Comment: Hint: the no torsion in the kernel is a key hypothesis. Assume the isomorphic copy is mapped to something else. What could it be? Can you get a contradiction?

Comment: If this exact sequence spits, I can find contradiction, but in general case, I have no idea how to find contradiction. Could you give it to the answer form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally let $H\subseteq A$ be a torsion (periodic) subgroup and let $f:A\to B$ be a group homomorphism such that $\ker f$ is torsion free. Then $H$ and $f(H)$ are isomorphic.

Indeed, let $x\in H$, $x\neq e$. Then $f(x)\neq e$ because otherwise $x$ would belong to $\ker f$ which is torsion free while $x$ is of finite order. It follows that $f_{|H}$ is injective (it has trivial kernel) and thus the restriction $f_{|H}:H\to f(H)$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $A$ isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$, and let $K = \ker f$ (so $A/K \cong B$).

Then $H \cap K = 1$, so $HK/K \cong H/(H \cap K) \cong H$.